# Parsing web log file using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, regex-look-ahead

I have a web log file that contains numeric host data and alpha-numeric username data.
Here are a few lines from the log file:

```
189.254.43.43 - swift6867 [21/Jun/2019:15:53:00 -0700] "GET /architectures/recontextualize/morph/scale HTTP/1.0" 204 8976
20.80.28.12 - hagenes4423 [21/Jun/2019:15:53:01 -0700] "POST /harness HTTP/1.1" 404 28127
112.211.50.38 - - [21/Jun/2019:15:53:03 -0700] "DELETE /harness/e-business/functionalities HTTP/1.1" 405 7975
```

Sometimes, the username is replaced with a hyphen.

I want to extract only the data before the first square bracket, which is then to be converted into a list of dictionaries.  For example:

```py
example_dict = {"host":"189.254.43.43", 
                "user_name":"swift6867"}
```

This is the regex that I used:

```py
pattern = """
    (?P<host>[\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*[.][\d]*)     # host dictionary
    (?P<username>([\w]+|-)(?=\ \[))             # username dictionary 
"""

re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE)
```

The regex doesn't find any matches.  Only individual regex statements work.  By this I mean the regex for host dictionary will work if I comment out the regex for username dictionary, and vice versa.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you putting brackets [] around every character? They are just meant to pick one of the chars inside them

Comment: Good point, [] is redundant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAN4df/4/)):

```regex
^(?P<host>(?:\d+\.?){4})\s*-\s*(?P<user_name>[^\s-]*?)\s
```

To create list of dicts you can apply [`groupdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) on each [`Match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) object returned by [`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```py
import re
...
pattern = r'^(?P<host>(?:\d+\.?){4})\s*-\s*(?P<user_name>[^\s-]*?)\s'
result = [i.groupdict() for i in re.finditer(pattern, logdata, re.MULTILINE)]
```

---

A bit less steps will take this regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kAN4df/5)), so on bigger data it should be slightly faster:

```regex
^(?P<host>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s*-\s*(?P<user_name>[^\s-]*?)\s
```

Comment: Since I wanted instances of the second hyphen to be included in the username dictionary, I omitted the hyphen in [^\s-] and just used [^\s].  Thank you, for also making my question clearer!